# SharePoint 2013 - About the rendering of DeltaPlaceHolderMain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, for master templates, is there a reason why the following lines of code

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" IsMainContent="true" runat="server">-->
```

renders as a span tag???...

```
<span id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">
```

Considering that custom page layout content will be within this location, why does this not render as a div element?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be a *div* you have to set the *BlockElement*-attribute to true.

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" BlockElement="true" IsMainContent="true" runat="server">-->
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.ajaxdelta_properties.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.   Truly a beautiful option.